# OAuth 2.0 without https

Tags: facebook, oauth, https, oauth-2.0

I want to develop a social widget and I want client to use it using OAuth 2.But there may be 
cases where client does not use https.

So I looked at facebook developer tool and its mention that they use oauth2.0. However I have seen website using facebook login button and accessing permission from user but the website  don't have https.

How is it possible?

Or should I switch back to OAuth 1.0